# Javascript appendChild adds two br-tags in Nokiabrowser 7.3.1.33

Tags: javascript, symbian, nokiabrowser

I have a strange issue with NokiaBrowser 7.3.1.33. When i use Javascript's appendChild it add two br-tags after the appended element automatically.

```
var span1 = document.createElement("span");
span1.innerHTML = "span1";

var span2 = document.createElement("span");
span2.innerHTML = "span2";

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(span1);
div.appendChild(span2);

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
body.appendChild(div);
```

This will create the following html:

```
<div>
  <span>span1</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>span2</span>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

I have only managed to produce this on Nokia C5-03 with NokiaBrowser 7.3.1.33. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with that browser. I never knew, what is that empty space after the appended elements, I spent many hours trying to figure out that. Now, from your question, I know, that is a `<br>`. **Many thanks :)**

With this information I made a workaround: after appending an element, remove those linebreak tags with a simple command after the appending:

```
$('#something').append('anything');
$('#something br').remove();
```

Use with caution, it will remove all linebreaks from the parent of the appended element. There may be more sophisticated solutions too, for removing only those two appended linebreaks, but I think, this is the simplest.

I hope, it helps.

K.J.